# Changing the font color of a wordpress the_content() post

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am playing around with WordPress and trying to learn what it can and can't do. I am trying to change the font color from black to white in the index.php file.

I can change the background colour of the the_title(), that works but changing the colour of the the_content() does not seem to work.

I tried googling but haven't found much help about using CSS with PHP, if anyone knows a good page I could read that would be much appreciated.

Here is the code (Please excuse the formatting):

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>

    <p style="color:white"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
    <p style="color:white"><?php the_content(); ?></p>

<?php endwhile;
else : ?>
<p>Sorry no posts matched your criteria.</p>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content of a post is `html` and it contain many `elements` like `h2`, `h3`, `p`, `a`.
So if you want to apply css into its children tag:

```
<div style="color:white"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
```

Comment: Okay, but it works with the_title() so does that mean that the_title() never contains multiple elements?

By the way, your answer worked but I can't upvote your answer because I need 15 karma first.

Comment: Because `the_title` is `raw text`. You can mark it correct, thank you.